# Show that $a^4(b^2-c^2) + b^4(c^2-a^2)+c^4(a^2-b^2)$ is divisible by $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Show that $$a^4(b^2-c^2) + b^4(c^2-a^2)+c^4(a^2-b^2)$$ is divisible by $$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a).$$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: **please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem.** These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Note that $a^2(b-c)+b^2(c-a)+c^2(a-b) = (a-b)(a-c)(b-c)$ and $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that substituting any of the following yields 0:
$a=b, b=c, c=a, a=-b, b=-c, c=-a$.
Thus by the factor theorem (which still holds on multivariate polynomials), we have $a-b, b-c, c-a, a+b, b+c, c+a$ are factors of the expression respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Your term is $$(a-b) (a+b) (a-c) (a+c) (b-c) (b+c)$$